# using link_to for automatic links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been wondering if there's any way to make link_to helper work automatically for params that aren't id, for instance:

```
preview_page_path(:token => @page.token)
```

I want to use this syntax instead:

```
preview_page_path(@page)
```

I was hoping that Rails could somehow figure out (after reading routes.rb) that preview action is using :token param instead of :id.

What I want to achieve is that I have page model, which I call using id in the backend, and using token in the frontend, so I cannot override to_param method.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the to_param method

```
class Page
  def to_param
    token
  end
end
```

OR

Define a custom route for page

> match "/pages/:token" => "pages#preview"

In your controller, the old

> params[:id]

will be

> params[:token]

, and you can get the page from the DB using:

> Page.find_by_token(params[:token])

Comment: Thanks, but that I already know.. I'm asking if its possible to keep id routing and have token routing as well